# PSET5 Speller Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, cs50

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

#define BASE 256
//No of words in dicionary
unsigned int SIZE = 0;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 100800;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    char new_word[strlen(word) +1];

    strcpy(new_word, word);

    //Lowercase all words from the text to be spellchecked
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        new_word[i] = tolower(new_word[i]);
    }

    int n = hash(new_word);

    if( n > N)
        n = n % N;

    temp = table[n];

    if (temp != NULL){
    //Traverse and check word
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(temp->word, new_word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp->next == NULL && strcasecmp(temp->word, new_word) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned long h;
    unsigned const char *us;

    /* cast s to unsigned const char * */
    /* this ensures that elements of s will be treated as having values >= 0 */
    us = (unsigned const char *) word;

    h = 0;
    while(*us != '\0')
    {
        h = (h * BASE + *us) % N;
        us++;
    }

    return h;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char w[LENGTH+1];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    while(fscanf(file, "%s\n", w) != EOF)
    {
        int n = hash(w);

        if (n > N)
            n = n % N;

        //Incremet in the no of words
        SIZE++;

        //Creating a new node to assign the word
        node *nod = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(nod == NULL){
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(nod->word, w);

        //Adding the new node to main node
        nod->next = table[n];
        table[n] = nod;

    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    //No of words from load function
    return SIZE;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    //Loopin through the array of linked ist
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *temp = NULL;
        node *cursor = NULL;

        cursor = table[i];

        while(cursor->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    return true;
}
```

After a week of using valgrind I was able to get rid of all the memory leaks, but then I get this error. My hash function isnt the best right now. I am looking on how to implement the murmur hash funciton.help50 valgrind doesnt really help with which line of code is causing the seg fault. But I feel like it has something to do with the pointers.

Hers the Error Code

Asking for help...

```
/etc/profile.d/cli.sh: line 94:  6280 Segmentation fault      valgrind ./speller texts/cat.txt
```

> Looks like your program is trying to access areas of memory that it isn't supposed to access. Did you try to change a character in a hardcoded string? Are you accessing an element of an array beyond the size of the array? Are you dereferencing a pointer that you haven't initialized? Are you dereferencing a pointer whose value is NULL? Are you dereferencing a pointer after you've freed it?

Its been almost a week. Cant seem to figute it out.

Comment: try to run `valgrind  --track-origins=yes ./speller texts/cat.txt` and add `-g` to the compile flags to get debug infos.

Comment: First of all  you need to learn some common debugging techniques. For example [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or *printf debugging*. And of course how to use an actual *debugger* to find locations of crashes in your code. With a debugger you can also examine values of variables at the time of the crash, and even use it to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values to see how they change.

Comment: For a debugger (including Valgrind) to properly work you need to make sure you build with debug information. For e.g. GCC or Clang add the flag `-g` when building.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did that and I get error "could not open -g".

Comment: @mch I get an error with "could not open -g".

Comment: post the actual command line that resulted. it sounds like it was wrong.

Comment: @underscore_d help50 valgrind ./speller texts/cat.txt -g

Comment: @Megapunk They mean to compile the program with `-g`, not to run `valgrind` on it with `-g`.

Comment: @underscore_d I am a noob. what should be my command line.

Comment: How do you get the program `speller` from the C code above? Build button in the IDE? Which IDE? Look for compiler settings or C settings.

Comment: @mch its cs50's cloud IDE. to build the program i use make speller. I will look into settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in unload  `while(cursor->next != NULL)` provokes the seg fault when `table[i]` is not populated. If no words are in that index, there is no such thing as `cursor->next`.